# How to implement a button onclicklistener inside recycler view kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

How to implement a button inside recycler view. The below is my adapter class. In my recycle view
layout my button id is. `btn_notify`. Where do I handle the event. Should I handle the event inside on `onBindViewHolder`? I am not sure where to implement in on click listener inside the adapater.

````
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.R
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.User2

class MyAdapter2(private val userList: ArrayList<User2>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item2,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)



    }
    

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user:User2 = userList[position]
        holder.name.text= user.name
        holder.phone.text= user.phone
        holder.address.text =user.address
        holder.bloodGroup.text= user.bloodgroup
        holder.io = user.id

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfirstname1)
        val phone :TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvphone11)
        val address : TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvaddress1)
        val bloodGroup: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvbloodg1)
        val id: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvid)
        var io: String? = ""
        var button: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_notify)
 }
} ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer ViewBinding or DataBinding rather than passing the views or using findViewById.

To answer your question, I think there are two ways to go.

1. You can implement the set on click listener inside the onBindViewHolder itself
2. You can create a function called bind() inside the RecyclerView.ViewHolder and call it.(Preferable as you might have multiple viewholders and this looks cleaner when using multiple viewholders)

```
1 .

 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user:User2 = userList[position]
        holder.name.text= user.name
        holder.phone.text= user.phone
        holder.address.text =user.address
        holder.bloodGroup.text= user.bloodgroup
        holder.io = user.id
        holder.button.setOnClickListener{
    //todo: enter code here
        }
    }



2.
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
      holder.bind(holder.itemView)
}
 
public class MyViewHolder(itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
fun bind(){
     var button: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_notify)
     button.setOnClickListener{
        //todo: do something
     }
     view.setOnClickListener{
        if(){
             //todo: do something
        }else{
             //todo: do something
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error when typing method2. I have along list of view holder.  Also flaw occurs inside app when doing method1 as I have long view holder list.

Comment: Can you check method 2 again

Comment: Sorry...it was not holder.findViewById inside the bind function. It was itemview(which is your root).findviewbyid. I am not passing any holder.

Comment: Also getting error when typing `holder.bind(holder,user)`

Comment: passing the wrong parameters...please check the parameters recieveing match the passing ones.